# Python - list comprehension

Tags: python

I have the following list:

```
fruits = ['apple', 'cherry', 'banana', 'lemon']
```

And using a list comprehension, i need to generate a list that contains the fruits (in uppercase) that contain the letter 'a', so apple and banana.

I tried using:

```
small=[s.upper() for s in fruits for c in s if c=='a']
```

But it gives me a result with duplicates:

```
['APPLE', 'BANNANA', 'BANNANA', 'BANNANA']
```

How can i fix that? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
[s.upper() for s in fruits if 'a' in s]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
[s.upper() for s in fruits if 'a' in s]
```

The reason your list comprehension doesn't work is because it expands to this:

```
result = []
for s in fruits:
     for c in s:
         if c == 'a':
             result.append(s.upper ())
```

This will go through every character in `fruit` and keep all those fruits that have an 'a' in them, in proportion to how often 'a' appears in each fruit.

Comment: but then it only gives me 'APPLE' and not 'BANANA'... the word doesn't necessarily have to start with 'a', it could contain it anywhere.

Comment: @Gambit2007: That wasn't clear to me. Edited my answer to the right answer.

Comment: Excellent answer considering this is the only one that explains why there were duplicates!

Answer (score 1):

You have two for loops in there but you only need one. Also, you're checking only the first character for 'a', but from the text I understand that 'a' could appear anywhere in the input. Plus, while this is not the case in your example, I assume it should also work for input strings that are not all-lowercase (like 'Apple'), so you should `lower()` the string before comparing with 'a'.

```
[s.upper() for s in fruits if 'a' in s.lower()]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[fruit.upper() for fruit in fruits if 'a' in fruit]
```

List comprehension can be a bit hard to comprehend. In this case it should be read from the middle out. You loop over all fruits (yeah, I know...), filter only those with 'a's in them and then convert them to upper case.